# Animating an emoticon to wink with animation in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, canvas

I am attempting to animate an emoticon that was previously drawn in canvas. I am attempting to do a draw and clear using frames following a tutorial but am not getting results. I have 6 frames of the emoticon coded and am unsure how to include this within the code. This is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Adding Animation</title>
<style>
  canvas {
    border: 3px #CCC solid;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" height="1200" width="900"></canvas>
  </div>
  <script>
     var mainCanvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
     var mainContext = mainCanvas.getContext("2d");

var canvasWidth = mainCanvas.width;
var canvasHeight = mainCanvas.height;

function drawCircle() {
    mainContext.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

    // color in the background
    mainContext.fillStyle = "#EEEEEE";
    mainContext.fillRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

    // draw the circle
        ctx.beginPath(); 
        ctx.strokeStyle = "000000";
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
        ctx.arc(600, 450, 150, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();

        //The smile
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctxstrokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.arc(600, 475, 75, .1 * Math.PI, Math.PI * .9, false)
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();

        //The eyes
        //Left
        ctx.save();
        ctx.scale(0.65, 1);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(850, 405, 40, 0 * Math.PI, Math.PI * 2, false);
        ctx.fillStyle="black";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.restore();

        //Right
        ctx.save();
        ctx.scale(0.65, 1);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(1000,405,40, 0*Math.PI, Math.PI*2, false);
        ctx.fillStyle="black";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.restore()
  }
drawCircle();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am unsure if I am even on the right track as I have a difficult time with animation. Does anyone have any suggestions they can give me guidance on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 names for the context: `mainContext` & `ctx`.

Change it to a single name and your face is "smiley" ! :-)

[image] ... [image]

**To animate:**

Use a `requestAnimationFrame` loop to change the `scaleY` value in `scale(scaleX,scaleY)` over time.

**Here's annotated code and a Demo:**

```js
var mainCanvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
var ctx = mainCanvas.getContext("2d");

var canvasWidth = mainCanvas.width;
var canvasHeight = mainCanvas.height;

ctx.translate(-425,-275);

drawCircle(1);

// global var to hold pct the left eye is open
// 1==fully open, 0==fully closed
var scaley=1;
var direction=-1;
// request 1 animate() loop 
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
function animate(time){
  // draw smiley with the specified eye openness
  drawCircle(scaley);
  scaley+=.02*direction;
  if(scaley<0){
    scaley=0;
    direction=1;
  }
  if(scaley>1){
    scaley=1;
    direction=-1;
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}


function drawCircle(scaleY) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

  // color in the background
  ctx.fillStyle = "#EEEEEE";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

  // draw the circle
  ctx.beginPath(); 
  ctx.strokeStyle = "000000";
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
  ctx.arc(600, 450, 150, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();

  //The smile
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctxstrokeStyle = "black";
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.arc(600, 475, 75, .1 * Math.PI, Math.PI * .9, false)
  ctx.stroke();

  //The eyes
  //Left
  ctx.save();
  // move the [0,0] origin to the left eye's centerpoint
  ctx.translate(550,405);
  // close the left eye by the specified scaleY
  ctx.scale(0.65, scaleY);
  ctx.beginPath();
  // draw the left eye (arc) at 0,0 because
  // we translated the origin to [550,405] earlier
  ctx.arc(0, 0, 40, 0 * Math.PI, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.fillStyle="black";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.restore();

  //Right
  ctx.save();
  ctx.scale(0.65, 1);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(1000,405,40, 0*Math.PI, Math.PI*2, false);
  ctx.fillStyle="black";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.restore()
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" height="1200" width="900"></canvas>
```

Comment: How would you make the eye "open" back up, reversing the animation?

Comment: @phoenixCoder. Yep, that's exactly right ... just reverse the animation when the eye is fully closed. I've edited the demo to show the eye both winking closed and also reopening. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You never declared a `ctx` variable.
Change all your `mainContext` by `ctx` and it should be working fine.